# Is there a way to grab the current item id on mouse over in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover

I have a method in javascript and i'm trying to grab the id of an element on mouse over, is there a way to do this?

So say I have a method which takes no arguments

```
function noArgs() {}
```

and I have two paragraphs with the id of p1 and p2, how could I get the id of the hovered paragraph?

EDIT: This is currently how I'm grabbing the id's, which I want to eliminate the "element" argument in the method

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" href="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hoverButton(element) {
                var button = document.getElementById(element);
                switch (button.state) {
                    case "up":
                        button.style.backgroundPosition = "top";
                        button.state = "down";
                        break;
                    default:
                        button.style.backgroundPosition = "bottom";
                        button.state = "up";
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button {
                background-image: url("images/button.png");
                width: 100px;
                height 50px;
                background-position: top;
                border: none;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" class="button" value="Submit" state="up" onmouseover="hoverButton('submit_button')" onmouseout="hoverButton('submit_button')"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_button2" class="button" value="Submit" state="up" onmouseover="hoverButton('submit_button2')" onmouseout="hoverButton('submit_button2')"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your method and how you're wiring it to your elements

Comment: Easy in jQuery :) - http://jsfiddle.net/MTfPE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
$element.bind('mouseover', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to eliminate the element argument?

In your scenario, you could do `onmouseover="hoverButton(this)"` and dispense with the `var button = document.getElementById(element);` line from your function.  `element` would then be whichever element was being moused-over at the time, and you could get its ID (should you want it) by doing `element.id`.

However, as you've got a reference to jQuery in your code, you might as well use it ;)